# How can I vertical align a double arrow (&raquo;) which has bigger height than text beside?

Tags: html, css

I want to align a big double arrow `&raquo;` which has 3rem size so that is is in one line with the text beside (1.5rem size). I've tried to align it with margins and paddings. But that doesn't change anything.

Here is my Code

```css
.box {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: Verdana;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.arrow {
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
My Text <span class="arrow">&raquo</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `&raquo;` is a **quote** character, not an arrow. If you want an arrow then use [an arrow](https://www.key-shortcut.com/en/writing-systems/35-symbols/arrows)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding `position:relative` to the icon might help you out..

```css
.box {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: Verdana;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.arrow {
  position:relative;
  top:5px;
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
My Text <span class="arrow">&raquo</span>
</div>
```

Comment: hee - hee - thats exactly what I did in my solution and I was downvoted for it - until your solution showed up doin gthe exactly same approach as mine. Thanks

Comment: I wrote this answer then saw your's ..I upvoted yours for answering before me ;)...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```css
.box {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: Verdana;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.arrow {
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
My Text <span class="arrow">&raquo</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply apply `position: relative` to the icon and position it as desired.

All I am doing is adding  `position:relative` and a `top: 0.5rem` to the icon and what that does is to set its position relative to its normal position in the page flow.

```css
.box {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: Verdana;
  border-radius: 30px;
  
}

.arrow {
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0.5rem
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
My Text <span class="arrow">&raquo</span>
</div>
```

Comment: To the downvoter - why? - altering the position and adding an offset via CSS is a well established approach of adjusting the position of an element. And yes I could have been more creative and used an ::after pseudoelement etc - or done dome other funky thing - but the simple truth is that this solution not only works - it is a common approach used by many.

Comment: It relies on pixel perfection. It relies on the user not being zoomed in or using one of the accessibility tools for larger font sizes. It also makes it more cumbersome to change the font size later. The superior approach is to use a tool that does not care about specific pixel values, such as `line-height` or flexbox.